# int has no len error Help me please?

Tags: python

I have a problem with my program  and it's really annoying me I keep getting an error I don't even know why can you please help me?

I Keep getting the builtins.TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() error

when it gets to the password verfication stage and I cannot figure out what the problem is..

```
#Program asking for a username, password and security pin 
#Written by Cole Johnston
#19/08/13 - 

#Declare/Initialize variables
sFirstName = "" #User's input of their first name (the minimum is 2 characters) (string) 
sLastName = "" #User's input of their last name (the minimum is 4 characters) (string)
sPassword = "" #User's input of their password (it must have a minimum length of 6 characters and a maximum length of 10 characters. It must contain at least 2 numbers in the password, it is case sensitive)
iPinNo = 0 #User's chosen input of security pin (It must be 4 characters long and contain only numbers which are single digit and range between 0-9)
iCount = 0 #The amount of times the user enters an invalid username (integer)
sMessage = "" #Message for user (string)
iFirstNameCheck=0 #Checks first name
iLastNameCheck=0 #Checks last name
iPasswordCheck=0 #Checks password
iPinNoCheck=0 #Checks pin
sUserName = "" #Creates a username for the user (uses first and last name)
sPasswordVerification = "" #Checks the password is correct and same as the first one

def APFirstERROR(): 
    print(("ERROR: Incorrect Attemps consisting of 3 \n\t Closing program")) 
    sys.ext


def APSecondERROR(): 
    print (("ERROR: Incorrect Attemps consisting of 3 \n\t Closing program")) 
    sys.ext

def APThirdERROR(): 
    print (("ERROR: Incorrect Attemps consisting of 3 \n\t Closing program")) 
    sys.ext

def APFourthERROR(): 
    print (("ERROR: Incorrect Attemps consisting of 3 \n\t Closing program")) 
    sys.ext


#Ask for the users First name 

while len(sFirstName) <2:  
    sFirstName=input("Could you please enter your first name: ")  
    if len(sFirstName) <2:  
        print("\tERROR: I'm sorry, you must enter a minumum of two characters") 
        FirstName = "" 
        iFirstNameCheck = iFirstNameCheck +1
        print (iFirstNameCheck, "Incorrect attempt") 
        if iFirstNameCheck == 3: 
            APFirstERROR() 

#Ask for the users Last name        
while len(sLastName)  <4: 
    sLastName = input("Could you please enter your last name: ") 
    if len(sLastName) <4 : 
        print ("\tERROR: I'm sorry, you must enter a minumum of four characters") 
        LastName = "" 
        iLastNameCheck = iLastNameCheck +1
        print (iLastNameCheck, "Incorrect attempt") 
        if iLastNameCheck==3: 
            APSecondERROR()    

sUsername = "Congratulations, your username will be " + sLastName[0:4] + sFirstName[0:1] 
print (sUsername)            


while sPassword is "": 
    sPassword=input("Could you please enter a password: ") 
    if len(sPassword) <6 or len(sPassword) >10 : 
        print("ERROR: I'm sorry, your password must be 6 characters or more but not exceeding 10 characters.\nPlease try again") 
        if sum(c.isdigit() for c in sPassword) <2: 
            print("Im sorry, your password does not contain enough numbers.\nThe requirements are a minimum of 2 numbers")         
            sPassword="" 
            iPasswordCheck=iPasswordCheck+1
            print(iPasswordCheck, "Incorrect Attempt") 
            if iPasswordCheck ==3: 
                sPassword="Incorrect"
                APErrorThird()             
                break 

#Verify the password 
while sPasswordVerification is "": 
    sPasswordVerification=input("Please enter your password a second time for verification: ") 
    if sPasswordVerification==sPassword:
        print("That password is Accepted") 
        if not sPasswordVerification==sPassword: 
            sPasswordVerification="" 
            print ("I'm sorry, that password is: Not accepted") 

                a
#ASk user for pin creation 
while len(iPinNo) <4: 
    iPinNo= input("Now could you please create a pin number. The requirements are that it must be only numbers (0-9). Must be 4 numbers long\n\tpin=?\t\n:") 
    if not re.match("^[1-9]*$", iPinNo): 
        print ("ERROR: I'm sorry but only numbers between 1-9 are allowed!") 
        if len (iPinNo) <4: 
            print ("I'm sorry, your pin number MUST be 4 characters.") 
            iPinNoCheck=iPinNoCheck+1
            print (iPinNoCheck, "Incorrect Attempt") 
            if iPinNoCheck==3: 
                iPinNo ="Incorrect"
                APErrorFourth()                 

#Display the Username, the Password and the Pin number

print ("Okay, " + (sFirstName) +" Your username is: ",sUsername) 
print("And, Your password is: ",sPassword)   
print ("Finally , Your Security pin is: ",iPinNo)
```

Comment: You should consider "initializing" your variables to `None`, then testing it with `if x is not None:` instead of a mixture between 0 and empty string initialization

Comment: Please localise your problem a little further. Surely not all your code is relevant to the problem, and you haven't even indicated which line the error occurs at, or your attempts at debugging things. (E.g. what are the values of the variables in the statement that fails? Don't ask us to simulate your code in our heads.)

Comment: Also: three levels of nested `if`s under a `while` is pretty bad. More so that you clearly know functions since you're using them for error reporting.

Comment: Why are you using double parens in your prints? And what do you think `sys.ext` will do?

Comment: Also: Python gives you tracebacks for a reason. Even if the tracebacks don't tell _you_ exactly what went wrong, they will usually tell the people you're asking for help.

Answer (score 4):

Here: `while len(iPinNo) < 4:`

`iPinNo` is an integer, and you're not supposed to call `len()` on integers (hence the error): the object passed to `len()` must be a sequence or a mapping.

Convert it to a string first, using `str()`, then call `len()`, to get the amount of digits.

Comment: While this is true, a salient question is *why* is `iPinNo` an integer? The answer is because OP is using `input` and should be using `raw_input`.

Comment: @kojiro OP is using Python 3. `iPinNo` is an integer because he does `iPinNo = 0` at the beginning

Comment: Do you say that because he uses parentheses around `print` "arguments"? That could be Python 2.7.

Comment: @kojiro I say that because he also uses `input()` for asking for the user to enter his name and last name. He'd be having NameErrors.

Comment: Good point. We should really *require* version tags on questions like this. :P

Comment: @kojiro You know, I might make a meta post about that. That's a good point

Comment: Superfluous comment: Another way to find out how many digits are in a number is `1 + int(math.log(number, base))`. Don't ask me when that'd be useful, but sometimes purists don't want to convert a number to a "string". ;)

Comment: Could somebody help me out also with the password and password verification section now, as the pin is working :)

Comment: @user2813115 De-indent the `if not sPasswordVerification==sPassword:` code block.

Answer (score 0):

There's no len() method for `int`, len() is for sequence

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

Definition:
Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's useful to paste the actual traceback so we can see where in the stack (and at what line in your code) the exception was thrown.

Anyway, several times in your code you ask the for the length of an integer number. For example

```
while len(iPinNo) < 4:
```

`int` types have no length. If you want to ensure the number is 4 digits long, you can either do

```
while len(str(iPinNo)) < 4:
```

or

```
while 999 < iPinNo < 10000:
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of digits of a decimal number, use the (base 10) logarithm.

```
from math import log10, ceil
ceil(log10(iPinNo))
```

The logarithm of 0 is undefined, so you've got to check that before testing the length.

---

Anyway, why not just testing against the matching power of 10?

```
while iPinNo < 10000:
```

or

```
while iPinNo < 10**5
```

Comment: heh, maybe a PyInt should really have a `__len__(self, radix=10)` method after all. :)

Comment: @kojiro: It's already got `bit_length`; implementing `digit_length(radix=10)` would be pretty simple. But I wouldn't call it `__len__`…

Comment: @abarnert Nobody understands my sense of humor, particularly when it comes to inappropriately commandeering Python's extensibility.

Comment: @kojiro: As far as I know, there's nothing in the Python reference documentation that requires that `int` be stored in binary form, so why isn't `digit_length` more appropriate than `bit_length`? :)